# Resolving DNS in ASP.NET (MVC) to Host Name/Proxy

Tags: c#, dns, ip, hostname

Alright, this question sounds a bit stupid, I know. I've looked at some of the other questions about it and I'm getting inconsistent results, even though I am finding the right answers. I'll try to lay it out as plainly as I can.

I have a problem where a large number of visitors to my site are using a ...I use the term popular very loosely, internet service (AOL) to access it. This is beyond my control. It is a large part of the userbase and I cannot stop them from using its built in browser (which derives from IE).

Now, this isn't the inherit problem. The problem is that any sites accessed through the browser go through one of their proxies. This does not cause any conflicts, but we need to know who is unique and who isn't for some specific reasons.

I have an installation of a popular message board system called "Invision Power Board". It tracks people's IP Address's and it has a feature to resolve an IP. So, I can click on an IP, and it will 'resolve' to a host like ..

IP `XX.XXX.XX.XXX` resolves to `cache-dtc-ae16.proxy.aol.com`.

Now I understand kind of what is going on here. `cache-dtc-ae16.proxy.aol.com` is a proxy, so I can't do much about that. I've come to terms with that. The code that does this is in IPB, and I don't speak PHP, so I'm SOL in that department.

I know how to get a User's IP Address.

```
HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress
```

What I want to know is this ... from an IP, how can I 'resolve' to that proxy, in C#? I basically want to setup a specific part of code that denies anything from a proxy that has .aol. in it.

Does what I am trying to make any sense, is it even feasible or possible? I may be completely missing the terminology. I **believe** I understand this much.

```
UserHostAddress is the **client's** IP Address
```

Here is what I have tried, basically.

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress)).Aliases
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you trying to get the domain name from the ip?
it looks like your answer is in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439773/c-get-a-domain-name-basing-on-the-ip-address)

```
IPHostEntry IpToDomainName = Dns.GetHostEntry("209.85.129.103");
string HostName = IpToDomainName.HostName; //it returns "fk-in-f103.1e100.net"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of TCP protocol. The address is part of the TCP packet and as far as I know, routers and switches and NATs and proxies change the address and put their own.

As far as I know, there is no way around it. Proxy's address is as good as you gonna get.

I believe even TCP packet's MAC (physical) address is going to be proxy's but that is something to look at although not sure if you can get that in ASP.NET runtime since a request can come in multiple TCP packets.

Comment: Forgive me, I am a rookie programmer and know little of networking (working on that, still stuck in IoC/DI/ORM). I do not understand exactly what you are saying. Can you translate to 'retard' speak?

Comment: Well, what you are doing is correct but it is a bit futile since I am not aware of **(but maybe someone else is and I would love to know the solution)** any means that with absolute certainty, you can identify user's address. Just use `HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress` and that as good it gets - I am afraid. Let's just wait for others to comment as well, maybe they know a way.

Comment: Somehow, the IPB Software is able to do it, so I *know* it can be done. I just don't know how to do it in C#....

Comment: Aah! I have solved it! The code was right, the entire time. I just wasn't passing through the proxy. It was disabled!

Answer (score 0):

try this

[NullifyNetwork - A comprehensive Microsoft DNS Server management implementation in C#](http://www.nullify.net/Article/304.aspx)